# when combining two lists into dictionary, only the last objects are passed on to the dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi i am trying to combine two lists created from a csv file, into a dict.
but the dict only contains the last objects from the lists.
What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: Btw dict keys are unique, that is why you are getting only latest values

Comment: Downvoted because of the picture. In addition to pasting your code. Please also give some example data of your problem as well. For guidance please read [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok sorry, will read the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You override the key everytime in the construction of your dict. The following code will have the values for debit and credit in a list. When printing it should like this: `{"credit" : [...], "debit": [...]}`.

```
credit_list = []
debit_list = []
combination = zip(dc_list, amount_list)
for key, value in combination:
    if key == "credit":
        credit_list.append(value)
    elif key == "debit":
        debit_list.append(value)

mydict = {"credit": credit_list, "debit": debit_list}
```

**Note:** Above is the way how to post code in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try and make a JSON

Comment: @BenjaminLundquistThomsen As I think of it, a JSON will also not work :/ is there a reason it cannot be a list of tuples for instance? Why does it need to be a JSON or dictionary?

Comment: It did not need to be a JSON, I was just confused.